# Recordset of a listBox in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I'm developing an application using MS Access and VBA.
Unfortunately i have this problem:

I set the recordset of a listBox using VBA and a query

```
'In the select, i select 4 fields
SQL = "..."        
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open SQL, Conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Set Me.MyList.Recordset = rs
        Me.MyList.SetFocus
    Else
        Set Me.MyList.Recordset = Nothing
        Me.MyList.SetFocus
    End If
rs.Close
```

The problem is that when i execute this piece of code it works but only if i set the number of the columns of my listBox at 1 or 2. 
I need to show 4 column, so, this for me is a problem.

I also have tried to decompile the application, but nothing has changed.

Can anyone tells me how to resolve it?
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Column Count` on the properties window to 4 and also define the column widths in the form of `0cm;1.217cm;2.064cm;3.545cm`.

You can do this at design mode or by code:

```
Dim sql_ As String
    sql_ = "Your SQL command..."

    With Me.MyList
        .ColumnCount = 4
        .ColumnWidths = "0cm;1.217cm;2.064cm;3.545cm"
        .RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
        .RowSource = sql_
    End With
```